# Packageinfo firstinstalltime wrong for some system / vendor apps

Tags: android, android-package-managers, android-applicationinfo

While capturing a list of all installed packages (using packageManager.getInstalledPackages(flags)) I noticed that some vendor pre-installed (mostly) and a few system android apps (like Downloads and Cell broadcast) have a wrong firstinstalltime value. The date of these apps ranges from 01/01/1970 01:01:33 - 20/06/1970 05:59:52 and I can't find a logical explanation....?

It's strange because most of the other system and pre-installed vendor apps give a reasonable date...

I was wondering if there's any other way to find out the installation date of an app, to overcome this bug?

Comment: just a guess: maybe they weren't installed the same way? since they ship with the system they might have been deployed by some other means or maybe they have just been around unchanged since before they added firstInstallTime?